# Xwindows troubles

Tags: linux-mint

if someone could give me a hand in the clarification of this question would be very grateful, is as follows:
Linux Mint desktop environment with compiz that ran fine until the update nvidia driver "graphics card" that after upgrading all left the dark, this problem was solved the driver revert to the previous version, the real problem is that the environment Compiz and its effects no longer work, noting that the graphic environment in use was the "same compiz" not gnome, kde or otherwise try to restore the environment but does nothing to have some positive result, everything works as it always normal internet, etc. ... just this problem with compiz that conflicts that we can not restore their status ...
Recalling that the detail is that the "Compiz" which is the window manager and no other!

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=nvidia%20driver%20compiz%20linux%20mint&es_th=1 Is the whole paragraph a single sentence? Please clarify the exact steps you took.

Comment: Yes it's a question about this unforeseen problem with Compiz Nvidia.

Comment: -Yeah! Yes, it was a single issue itself, yes ...
thanks for listening but we could already solve the problem ... was a small hardware defect that occurred to me, a small component that could not stand the heat where walking around here where the system is used you just bursting on the video card and ended causing all this disorder.

Comment: I am glad you solved it Paulo. A friendly tip: in written communications like this, writing in short sentences with proper punctuation helps the reader to properly understand you. :D